# C# - Windows Forms - Visual Studio - Search music location

Tags: c#, forms

I have a problem!
I created a program and I put it a song, but I wanted the program to search the music inside the musics folder to play it.

```
player.SoundLocation = "musics\advm.wav";
```

It does not work.
It's as if he searches for the file "musics \ advm.wav" directly.
Help Me!

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Does it work if you give the **full** path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as Lei stated, you may just have to give it the full path. The current state you have the SoundLocation assumes this "musics\" folder is within the working or running directory.

So if the .wav file's folder is not in the same location as your application's exe, then just specify the full path.

Example:

```
player.SoundLocation = @"C:\Users\Chris\Music\advm.wav";
```

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it worked out for you. Good luck with the rest of your project!